# How to get all the dates between the date range (inclusive start_date and end_date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get all the dates between start_date and end_date, including start_date and end_date?

But not those dates that do not fall in the range.

eg: 08-01-2020 should not be in the output because it is not in any of the work_id dates range
so 08-01-2020 is one of the non-working dates

So I want all the dates except the non-working dates.

Sample table :
[image]

Sample output :
either this

[image]

or this

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: @jarlh work_id is int and rest are date and I am using SQL server

Comment: @jarlh can you please help me now

Comment: Have a calendar help table, or a cte, with all dates of interest. OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh can you please help me with the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of dates of target range, add working and non-working flags to the list, and filter by the flag.
You can get the expected output with the following query.

```
-- 1st, generate a list of dates
with dates as (
select min(start_date) as dates, max(end_date) as max_date from dates_range
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, dates), max_date from dates
where dates < max_date
),
-- 2nd, generate a list of dates with working/non working flag
all_dates as (
select distinct
  d1.dates,
  case when d2.work_id is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as working
  from dates as d1 left outer join dates_range as d2
  on d1.dates between d2.start_date and d2.end_date
)
-- 3rd, filter either that working is true or false
select dates as Non_working_dates from all_dates where working = 'false';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ea1e5818830a7301f3974e127cf3640)

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a table valued function that generates a list of dates for each entry in your table

```
CREATE FUNCTION DatesByRange(@start_date date, @end_date date)
    RETURNS @Dates TABLE 
    (
        Dates date
    )
AS
BEGIN
    
    WITH cteDateRanges AS
    (
        SELECT @start_date AS workday
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, workday) FROM cteDateRanges
        WHERE workday < @end_date
    )

    INSERT INTO @Dates
    SELECT workday FROM cteDateRanges

    RETURN;
END;
```

Then you can use this function with a cross apply

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY(SELECT * FROM dbo.DatesByRange(t.start_date, t.end_date)) x
```